# CreateWindow throwing access violation from pointer from managed handleref

Tags: wpf, winapi, c++-cli, interop

I may be way out of my depth here, so I'm sorry if I seem completely lost, but it's just because I am.  (But, if I never went out of my depth, I guess I'd never learn anything)

I'm trying to figure out how to host a Win32 window in a WPF control but, being completely unknowledgable about the Windows API, I'm struggling to interact with it in basic ways.

Currently, I'm getting an access exception when I try to pass the parent window's HWND to the method "CreateWindow."

Here is my code:

```
///------------- VisualDerived.h -----------------

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace POCPP
{
    namespace WPF
    {
        namespace Controls
        {
            public ref class VisualDerived : System::Windows::Interop::HwndHost
            {
            private:
                HWND *childWin;

            protected:
                virtual HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef trg) override;
                virtual void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef trg) override;

            public:
                VisualDerived();


            };
        }
    }
}

// ------------------ VisualDerived.cpp -----------------------

#include "Stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include "VisualDerived.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

HandleRef POCPP::WPF::Controls::VisualDerived::BuildWindowCore(HandleRef trg)
{
    DWORD windowOptions = WS_CHILDWINDOW;

    HWND *parentWindow = (HWND*)trg.Handle.ToPointer();

    HWND chld = CreateWindow(NULL, NULL, windowOptions, 0, 0, 200, 200, *parentWindow, 0, 0, NULL); // throws access exception as is, returns null reference exception without the pointer to the parentWindow

    return HandleRef(NULL, System::IntPtr(&chld));

}

void POCPP::WPF::Controls::VisualDerived::DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef trg)
{

}

POCPP::WPF::Controls::VisualDerived::VisualDerived()
{

}
```

Anyway, I'm sorry if my problem seems noobish to the seasoned professionals here.  I'm pretty far outside my comfort zone not knowing either the Windows API well, nor C++/CLI.

But I'm determined to learn how to do this, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HWND *parentWindow = (HWND*)trg.Handle.ToPointer();
```

is wrong because `Handle` is the `HWND`. Change it to:

```
HWND parentWindow = (HWND)trg.Handle.ToPointer();
```

You are passing `NULL` as the window class when you call `CreateWindow`. You have to provide a window class.

Your return statement is also wrong. You are returning the address of a local variable. It should be:

```
return HandleRef(NULL, System::IntPtr(chld));
```

Comment: Well, you took care of the access exception.  I did have to use "ToPointer" - I guess I was creating a pointer to a pointer and not thinking about it (it's a bit late) which explains the access exception.  Which parameter is the "Window Class?"  Is that "HINSTANCE?"  Sigh, I guess I need to look at this in greater depth.  Thanks for helping me with the pointer idiocy.  I need a book or something on the API.

Comment: The first parameter is the window class. That's stated in the documentation. You must read the documentation. Petzold's Programming Windows is as good as ever.

Comment: You mean the string?  I thought that was just a title - sigh, you're completely right  -- looking at the docs now -- I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I finally got the message pump working this morning after I called it a night last night.  I don't know how long I would have sat there trying to figure out what is going on without noticing that string was actually a designation of an object.